# mysql query for counting records

Tags: mysql

I have records in mysql table like

```
a
a
a
b
b
```

and I want output like:

```
a 3
b 2
```

Is there any mysql query that I achieve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SELECT field, COUNT(field) FROM table GROUP BY field